# Network manager disappeared on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, network-manager

After an update, the icon network manager disappeared from the panel. I tried to add it manually but:

```
bash> nm-applet
nm-applet-Message: using fallback from indicator to GtkStatusIcon`
```

I'm using gnome

Do you know what caused this ?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to uninstall with `sudo apt-get purge network-manager` 
and install it again with `sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome network-manager`. You may also try `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

This is me trying to make a somewhat more clear answer based on @EhudBottaro's answer, and I am in no way saying this is my fix, I am just clarifying.

It seems that you have removed the package of `network-manager` from Ubuntu, which honestly, I have done before. At first it can be scary and then stressful trying to figure out how to get it back but it is easy and simple to fix **(AS LONG AS YOU ARE CURRENTLY CONNECTED TO A NETWORK.)** If you are, do

```
sudo apt-get purge network-manager && sudo apt-get clean
```

That will 100% purge all files and packages related to network-manager, and you may  want to do a

```
sudo proccess reload network-manager
```

(If that ^^ Is not the right command feel free to edit, as I do not remember it exactly) Once that it done do:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get install network-manager ubuntu-desktop
```

So that you can try to fix all missing packages. If this doesn't work, please leave a comment so we can work this out. IF this does work, make sure to vote up and check so others who see this can fix it easily!